# Continuity of Connections

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Suppose I have a connection $\nabla$ in a riemannian manifold $M$. Let $X_n\rightarrow X$ be smooth vector fields converging in $C^{\infty}$. I was wondering if $\nabla _{X_n}Y\rightarrow \nabla_{X}Y$?

I think this is true , if we look in local coordinates in an open set that is contained in a compact set , we can bound the christoffel symbols and the terms appearing for $Y$ and then using the convergence I think we get the desired result.

However I wanted to make sure this was correct or If I am making some mistake.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean uniform convergence on compacts of all the derivatives?

Comment: You are correct. The same would not hold if it was $Y_n$ converging to $Y$ because $\nabla_{X} Y$ depends on the drivatives of $Y$

Comment: Remember that $\nabla_XY$ is $C^\infty$-linear in $X$, so all you should need is $C^0$ bounds on $X_n-X$.